# Textfile data not importable to third party application

Tags: c#

I am in the process of developing a windows application with 3 textboxes, the application reads an instrument's serial number via the serial port saves it as a string and displays the number on one of the textboxes. The user then manually enters the cpu number and mine number in the other 2 textboxes and the data is saved in textfile for importing to a third party app.if i try to import the textfile it doesn't work whereas if i type in the data manually the textfile imports with no problems but if i copy the same manually typed text file and try to import the copy it doesn't work also. Furthermore i observed that if i edit the serial number textbox (The one form the serial port) even by clearing and typing back the same serial number the produced textfile imports correctly.
A sample output text file looks like this 
`71A04619010000C7,99080101,132`
`71A04615430000B9,99080101,132`

Is there a difference between manually typing and using `StreamWriter`?

```
private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(SerialNumberTextBox.Text);
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append(CpuNumberTextBox.Text);
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.AppendLine(MineNumberTextBox.Text);

    using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\UserInputFile.txt", true))
    {
        await outfile.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the resulting text files - with a "wrong" and a "good" file?

Comment: Check file sizes. Maybe the problem is with encoding, maybe whitespace characters (space, tab, end of line) and their numbers are not the same, etc.

Comment: When you say *"if i try to import the textfile it doesn't work"*, do you have an exception or something? How do you define *"it doesn't work"*?